# Need help sending input variables to a terraform module sourced from S3

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I ran into a problem when I try to source a terraform module from S3. I have a module `api_module` that takes a couple of input variables `(name, environment)` from the caller. I did a zip of this module code and uploaded to S3, so that I can source it from S3 wherever I would like to.

When I source this module into another program from S3, terraform is not accepting setting any input variables. The same program accepts input variables if I source the module from a git repo.

Here is the sample code that I am talking about:

```
     source                 = "s3::http://s3.amazonaws.com/module_bucket/api_module.zip"
     name                   = "api_name"
     environment            = "tst"
}
```

terraform returns error while running *plan* stating that the input variables name and environment are not accepted.

The same code works good if I source the module from a git repo:

```
module "my_module" {
     source                 = "git::ssh://git@wwwin-github.com/api_module.git"
     name                   = "api_name"
     environment            = "tst"
}
```

I need some help on how could I send these input parameters to the module getting sourced from S3.

Thanks
- hyvrt

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it out with help in another portal.

My s3 archive had an extra layer which is causing the downloaded module to have an extra directory in the path. I fixed the archive to zip only the files not the folder. Now I don't see any issue sourcing the module from S3.

Thanks